# To access tables of one schema from another schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is my SP and I have KMDEPOT_DB, ILX2012_KMDEPOT schema's and I want to use the select statement to fetch data from tables of above mentioned schema's. When I execute directly as SQL statement like below it works fine

```
INSERT INTO KMDEPOT_DB.RUN_ITEM(RUN_ID, SOURCE_ID, MATCH_NAME, TOC_ID)
SELECT
JOB.LASTRUNID,
TOCINSTANCE.SOURCEID,
TOC.MATCHNAME,
TOC.TOCID
FROM
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI779_TOC TOC,
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI779_TOCINSTANCE TOCINSTANCE,
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.JOB
WHERE
TOC.TOCID = TOCINSTANCE.TOCID AND JOB.AOIID = 700;
```

If the same statement is put inside a PL/SQL SP then it gives table or view does not exists

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_rows (
table_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO KMDEPOT_DB.RUN_ITEM(RUN_ID, SOURCE_ID, MATCH_NAME, TOC_ID)
SELECT
JOB.LASTRUNID,
TOCINSTANCE.SOURCEID,
TOC.MATCHNAME,
TOC.TOCID
FROM
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI779_TOC TOC,
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI779_TOCINSTANCE TOCINSTANCE,
ILX2012_KMDEPOT.JOB
WHERE
TOC.TOCID = TOCINSTANCE.TOCID AND JOB.AOIID = 700;
END;
```

Why it is not working? any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your access to the `ILX2012_KMDEPOT` is via a role rather than via a direct grant.  If you want to create a definer's rights stored procedure (the default), you need to have all the privileges on the underlying objects granted directly to you not via a role.  Privileges granted via a role aren't available in a definer's rights stored procedure.

You can validate that this is the problem by disabling roles in your SQL*Plus session and then trying to run the `INSERT`.  If you do

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> <<your insert statement>>
```

I would expect that the `INSERT` would fail.  If it does, that confirms that the problem is that you're using privileges that are being granted via a role.

Comment: Yes, it fails. What kind of permission is required to execute a SP which access tables from 2 difference schema's

Comment: @Jey - The owner of the stored procedure would need to have appropriate privileges on whatever objects the stored procedure references granted directly to that user.  If the stored procedure is only selecting data from an object, the owner of the stored procedure would need to have `SELECT` privileges on the object.  If the stored procedure is also inserting, updating, or deleting data, the owner of the procedure would need to have `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and/or `DELETE` privileges on the object.